# find a constant in a nonlinear equation, with an array of data

Tags: python, scipy, nonlinear-functions

I have a nonlinear equation:

> p=x/(exp(-1*L*x)+4*exp(-1*L*y)+3*exp(-1*z))

and L is  constant and what I want to find. I have an array of data for (x,y,z,p).
I am able to pass a set of data to (p,x,y,z) to find L and result is fine, but 
How can I pass all the  array of data in order to find the best value for L.

```
import scipy.optimize

def f(L):
    b=p-x/(exp(-1*L*x)+4exp(-1*L*y)+3exp(-1*z))
    return b
print scipy.optimize.minimize(f,0)
```

I found some posts on using minimize or fsolve, but in my case is different. I want pass data to the variable to find the best value for constant parameter.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, you want to solve the given equation for _L_ for each combination of parameters _x, y, z, p_ in your dataset? What do you mean by "best value"?

Comment: L is constant and same values. What I mean is a value for L which is make the equation zero or minimum for all the data.. I could pass one set of data and fine L which make the equation almost zero, but when I pass the other set of data, the result is not accurate. I tried to pass all set of data one by one, find L for each one, and find the average, but still I am not convinced with the finding.